# How to add/update properties of a target project (SDK Style Format) upon custom NuGet package install?

Tags: c#, nuget

**Context**

I've got several different projects (20+ for both traditional and SDK style format projects) that I would like to have strong named. I wanted to create a NuGet package such that when installed on any of those target projects it automatically takes care of adding relevant properties.

It should only add add the required properties (`SignAssembly` + `AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile`)  in the target's .csproj. The actual building of the project is the CI pipielines job.

**Current Approach**

So far, I've created a folder with the following structure:

```
- content
    - Key.snk

- tools
    - install.ps1

- build
    - Package.props

- Package.nuspec
```

The `content` folder contains the strong name key file (.snk) and `tools` folder contains the powershell script to be run upon install of the NuGet package. The `build` folder contains the properties to be injected into the target .csproj.

This is what the `install.ps1` looks like:

```bsh
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$snkFilename = "Key.snk"

#Add the .snk file

$project.ProjectItems.AddFromFile($snkFilename)

#Set target .csproj properties

$project.Properties.Item("SignAssembly").Value = "True"
$project.Properties.Item("AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile").Value = $snkFilename

#Save the target project

$project.Save()
```

Here's how the `Package.props` file in build folder looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>Key.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)content\Key.snk">
      <Link>Key.snk</Link>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Here's how the `Package.nuspec` file in folder root looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>Package</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Rithin Chalumuri</authors>
    <description>Automatically add Key.snk to the project and sign the assembly with a strong name.</description>
    <contentFiles>
        <files include="content\Key.snk" buildAction="none" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="content\Key.snk" target="contentFiles\" />
    <file src="content\Key.snk" target="content\" />
    <file src="build\**" target="build" />
    <file src="tools\**" target="tools" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Finally, to build the package, I've run this command `NuGet pack Package.nuspec` when in the folder root.

**Problem**

This above works fine for projects with traditional format .csproj. It adds the `Key.snk` to the target project root and the required properties. But this approach does **not** work projects with in the SDK style format. It fails to update the .csproj or copy the contents to the target root.

After surfing the internet, I've read the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files) and came across a few stack overflow answers. They all are pointing in the direction that with newer SDK style format projects use `PackageReference` and that can only modify the build output.

Since the `install.ps1` script running upon NuGet install is deprecated for newer style projects. I've tried adding the `.props` file so it can inject the properties into the target .csproj, but that isn't working either.

So, for new SDK style project:

- How can I Include the `Key.snk` file in target project root or just reference it during target project build so that the assemblies are signed?
- How can I add/update the `SignAssembly` + `AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile` properties in the target .csproj files?

In general, is there is a better approach for this particular problem context?

Comment: Not only PowerShell in NuGet packages are deprecated, the usefulness of signing an assembly (strong naming) is also reduced. You didn't reveal enough about the context of why you want to enforce strong naming via a NuGet package, as in real world scenarios, that's the task of CI/CD configuration, not merely a project setting.

Comment: @LexLi, thanks for your quick reply. I've got several different projects (20+) that I would like to have strong named. To automate this, I wanted to create a NuGet package such that when installed on any of those target projects it automatically takes care of adding relevant properties. Wouldn't the build pipelines still need this project setting? (as we need to somewhere set this so it knows to string name the assembly when building)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that there is no convenient way to do this from a NuGet package any more. You just can't run any powershell any more and there are no plans to add it.

On the other hand, CI/CD pipelines are much better than they used to be. An SDK `.csproj` file is still just an XML file, and many CI/CD tools include the ability to modify files as a pre-build step. Depending on the environment you may also be able to include a step to copy the `.snk` into the build too (local file copy, git submodules, additional source folder etc) thus moving the whole functionality from NuGet to CI/CD which is arguably better anyway

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'll give this a go and update the answer. But, any ideas on why the MSBuild `.props` file above isn't injected into the target project file? This functionality isn't deprecated?

Comment: Sorry, I've used tools, lib and content before, never build